# Android geocoder API

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-geocoder

I'm trying to create an autocomplete textview to search for addresses and display them on my map, but i'm having some problems with the suggestion fetching.

For this i'm using the geocoder function getFromLocationName.

In order to get a response (and sometimes a pretty bad one) i have to input into the search a whole word plus a number, and for it to suggest something even close, the string has to be almost the same as the google name for that street.

Is there any other way yo make a street suggestion text field? So far i've solved the need for a number by adding " 1" to the input string if it didn't have any numbers in it, but it's still pretty far off of the way the suggestions work on google maps.

Thanks in advance for any tips you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

The Geocoder APis aren't designed for this type of request. Usually you feed the full name of the street/city/etc to it and it will translate it into coordinates.

Use the Google [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) instead. It will respones some suggestions for your input, which can be anything between one letter and the full address.

Note that you need to have a valid key to use this API.